# How do I change the icon for Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm having trouble changing my electron app icon.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 960,
    frame: false,
    icon: __dirname + 'img/joe.icns',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      // worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      // contextIsolation: true,
    },
```

I've referenced [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351575/how-to-change-electronjs-app-default-icon) and [medium.com](https://medium.com/fantageek/changing-electron-app-icon-acf26906c5ad) for my attempt.

I have also attemptted

```
icon: __dirname + 'src/img/joe.icns',
```

```
icon: __dirname + './img/joe.icns',
```

and other similar structure names.

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: as far as i know there must be a manifest.json where u set stuff like this. but i could be wrong

Comment: I'll look in to it ty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app#:~:text=app%2C%20usually%20in%20node_modules%2Felectron,the%20icon%20via%20cmd%2Bv

Comment: Thank you for the link, It solved the problem for me. @Deniz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
icon: path.join(__static, 'joe.icns'),
```

And put the icon in `./dist_electron/bundled` and `./public`

Comment: It resulted in a error code:
ReferenceError: __static is not defined ...

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351575/how-to-change-electronjs-app-default-icon), I assumed .icns (icon set) was the only extension allowed for electron apps. Reading [Stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529772/how-to-set-app-icon-for-electron-atom-shell-app#:%7E:text=app%2C%20usually%20in%20node_modules%2Felectron,the%20icon%20via%20cmd%2Bv) provided by @deniz, I've realized ico file type was also available and gave it a try, and it worked. I assumed icns was a complex icon file type, and my icns file was probably not compatible with electron app.
Thank you (and sorry) for the effort @Majed Badawi.

```
icon: __dirname + '/img/joe.ico',
```